# Binding parameter to complex type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

I have a navigation bar, with several links, like this:

`<a href="MyController/Browse/2">MenuItem1</a>`

This request would hit my action method:

```
public ActionResult Browse(int departmentId)
{
    var complexVM = MyCache.GetComplexVM(departmentId);
    return View(complexVM);
}
```

This is my `ComplexVM`:

```
public class ComplexVM 
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

`MyCache`, is a static list of departments, which I am keeping in memory, so when user passes in `DepartmentId`,  I wouldn't need to get the corresponding `DepartmentName` from DB.

This is working fine... but it would be nice if I could somehow initialize `ComplexVM` in custom model binder, instead of initializing it in the Controller... so I still want to use a link (menu item), but this time, a `CustomModelBinder` binds my parameter, 2, to `ComplexVM`: it needs to look up the name of department with id = 2 from `MyCache` and initialize `ComplexVM`, then `ComplexVM` would be passed to this action method:

```
public ActionResult Browse(ComplexVM complexVM)
{
    return View(complexVM);
}
```

I want to hit the above controller without doing a post-back, as I have a lot of menu item links in my navigation bar... not sure if this is possible? Or if this is even a good idea?

I have seen [this link](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/07/07/intelligent-model-binding-with-model-binder-providers/), which sort of describes what I want... but I am not sure how the routing would work... i.e. routing `id:2` => `ComplexVM`

---

Alternatively would it be possible to do this in `RouteConfig`, something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Browse",
    url: "{controller}/Browse/{departmentId}",
    // this does not compile, just want to explain what I want...
    defaults: new { action = "Browse", new ComplexVM(departmentId) });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can achieve this with little change and with one trick

```
<a href="MyController/Browse?id=1">MenuItem1</a>
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult Browse(ComplexVM complexVM)
{
return View(complexVM);
}
```

View model

```
public class ComplexVM
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public ComplexVM()
    {
        this.DepartmentId = System.Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request("id").ToString);
        this.DepartmentName = "Your name from cache"; // Get name from your cache 
    }
}
```

This is without using model binder. Trick may help.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible. It is also a good idea :) Off-loading parts of the shared responsibility to models / action filters is great. The only problem is because they are using some special classes to inherit from, testing them sometimes might be slightly harder then just testing the controller. Once you get the hang of it - it's better.

Your complex model should look like

```
// Your model class
[ModelBinder(typeof(ComplexVMModelBinder)]
public class ComplexVMModel
{
   [Required]
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

   public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

// Your binder class
public class ComplexVMModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
     // Returns false if you can't bind.
     public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext modelContext)
     {
         if (modelContext.ModelType != typeof(ComplexVMModel))
         {
             return false;
         }

         // Somehow get the depid from the request - this might not work.
         int depId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["DepID"];
         // Create and assign the model.
         bindingContext.Model = new ComplexVMModel() { DepartmentName = CacheLookup(), DepId = depId };

         return true;
     }
}
```

Then at the beginning of your action method, you check the ModelState to see if it's valid or not. There are a few things which can make the model state non-valid (like not having a `[Required]` parameter.)

```
public ActionResult Browse(ComplexVM complexVM)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //If not valid - return some error view.
    }
}
```

Now you just need to register this Model Binder.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ComplexVMModel), new ComplexVMModelBinder());
}
```

Your should be able to use the route config that you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I think my question is a bit confusing... I have a link like this: <a href="MyController/Browse/2">MenuItem</a>... how could I hit the Controller that you have explained from this link?

Comment: Added the application_start registration as well, just use defaults: new { action = "Browse" } in your route config and this should work

Comment: But shouldn't this condition be false?  if (modelContext.ModelType != typeof(ComplexVMModel)) - because I am passing an int not ComplexVM

Comment: No - because you are explicitly binding the ComplexVMModel. Basically your method is receiving an int but it's getting binded a different model

Comment: Hi Mavi, thanks again for your answer... Your answer is great and I have given you a +1 for it... but it explains how the custom model binder works... my question is about binding int to complexVM and your answer does not explain this... As I mention earlier, my modelContext.ModelType != typeof(ComplexVMModel) won't work as I am passing in int not ComplexVm...

Comment: The custom model binder should exactly do that and convert the int binding to a complexvmmodel though? So it shouldn’t really be a matter if you are passing int at that stage since you are binding the model in **custom** way

Comment: but then, every time I pass in an int, it should be bounded to ComplexVM... even for other action methods, which should not be the case... sorry, but I find it hard to believe...

Comment: No of course not. It would only try to bind it to a complexvm when you pass that not an int. But because you required the int in the model a complexvm without an int parameter would fail. Any regular int will still be bound to int.

Comment: For all other action methods if you pass complexvm as a param custom binder would come into play and look for department id int in the request. If you pass any other params which also includes int / it would not attempt to bind it to the complexvm model